# How to use Shibboleth authentication for a Yesod application?

Tags: haskell, yesod, shibboleth

How can I put a Yesod application behind Shibboleth authentication?

I currently have (without Yesod) my application as a CGI program,
and access to it is controlled by Apache-Shibboleth.

Now, we are moving to Yesod, so there is no more Apache. 
Or should there be (fastcgi)?

Comment: You will need to create it yourself, befause Shibboleth use ECP auth profile https://wiki.shibboleth.net/confluence/display/CONCEPT/ECP